# What is the formula for calculating a timestamp?

Tags: timestamp

Just a random question but does anyone know the formula for how a timestamp is calculated? I am guessing it has to consider each month and how many days, leap years, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are interested in implementation here is roughly how Windows timestamp can be calculated (also known as [ticks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx)):

```
public static Int64 GetTimeStamp(
                        int year, int month, int day,
                        int hour, int minute, int second, int milliseconds)
{
    Int64 timestamp = DateToTicks(year, month, day)
        + TimeToTicks(hour, minute, second);

    return timestamp + milliseconds * TicksInMillisecond;
}

static readonly int[] DaysToMonth365 =
    new int[] { 0, 31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334, 365 };
static readonly int[] DaysToMonth366 =
    new int[] { 0, 31, 60, 91, 121, 152, 182, 213, 244, 274, 305, 335, 366 };
const long TicksInSecond = TicksInMillisecond * 1000L;
const long TicksInMillisecond = 10000L;

public static bool IsLeapYear(int year)
{
    if ((year < 1) || (year > 9999))
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("year", "Bad year.");

    if ((year % 4) != 0)
        return false;

    if ((year % 100) == 0)
        return ((year % 400) == 0);

    return true;
}

private static long DateToTicks(int year, int month, int day)
{
    if (((year >= 1) && (year <= 9999)) && ((month >= 1) && (month <= 12)))
    {
        int[] daysToMonth = IsLeapYear(year) ? DaysToMonth366 : DaysToMonth365;
        if ((day >= 1) && (day <= (daysToMonth[month] - daysToMonth[month - 1])))
        {
            int previousYear = year - 1;
            int daysInPreviousYears = ((((previousYear * 365) + (previousYear / 4)) - (previousYear / 100)) + (previousYear / 400));

            int totalDays = ((daysInPreviousYears + daysToMonth[month - 1]) + day) - 1;
            return (totalDays * 0xc92a69c000L);
        }
    }
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
}

private static long TimeToTicks(int hour, int minute, int second)
{
    long totalSeconds = ((hour * 3600L) + (minute * 60L)) + second;
    if ((totalSeconds > 0xd6bf94d5e5L) || (totalSeconds < -922337203685L))
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

    return (totalSeconds * TicksInSecond);
}
```

Comment: I am wanting to write this in PHP.

Comment: @David: PHP's `time` and `gmmktime` functions returns Unix-timestamps. If you want you can convert it to ticks as `621355968000000000 + unixTimestamp * 10000000`

Comment: what is 0xd6bf94d5e5L, 0xc92a69c000L and 922337203685L?

Comment: @FaizanRupani that's maximum number of seconds/days you can represent with 64-bit integer. Have a look at the original source code: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/timespan.cs,272

Comment: 0xc92a69c000L is hex. 24 hours * 60 min * 60 seconds is seconds in a day, 86,400. If you convert hex to decimal (can probably find an online tool in a search engine), you will get 864000000000, which looks like a multiple of it.

Answer (score 7):

Here's an example of how Unix timestamp is calculated from the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time):

> The Unix time number is zero at the
>   Unix epoch, and increases by exactly
>   86 400 per day since the epoch. Thus
>   2004-09-16T00:00:00Z, 12 677 days
>   after the epoch, is represented by the
>   Unix time number 12 677 × 86 400 = 1
>   095 292 800. This can be extended
>   backwards from the epoch too, using
>   negative numbers; thus
>   1957-10-04T00:00:00Z, 4 472 days
>   before the epoch, is represented by
>   the Unix time number −4 472 × 86 400 =
>   -386 380 800.

Answer (score 2):

Usually it is the elapsed time since a specific date. In the case of unix time, it is the time elapsed since Jan 1, 1970 in seconds.