# Convert a "string of time" into a timestamp without 3rd party modules in Python

Tags: python, time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

What's a good way to convert a string of text (that represents a time) into a timestamp.

Times could come in various formats that are not predictable.

```
'January 2, 2012'
'2012-01-05 13:01:51'
'2012-01-01'
```

All outputs should be timestamps:

```
1325480400
1325786511
1325394000
```

The time.strptime() function requires that inputs be consistent. I'm parsing a list of user-submitted dates that have various time formats.

Comment: Is there a good reason why you cannot use `dateutil`?

Comment: @esaelPsnoroMoN Different question. I can't predict the format of the strings, so strptime() does no good. It's not a consistent format.

Comment: Use exceptions with `strptime()`

Comment: And there is not reliable way for guessing date format. Date formats can be ambigious. So what you are trying to do is partly weird.

Comment: @esaelPsnoroMoN These are coming from a list of user-submitted dates, I can't control the input.

Comment: @ensnare: Why can't you use 3rd party libraries? Can you use them if they satisfy certain license requirements?

Comment: If you have a limited set of date string formats, you could try to identify them using regexps an then take the necessary action to convert it using the available tools from python.

Comment: You could also try doing a depth-first search or something similar where you try different combinations of tokens using strptime(), if you don't need the input processing to be blazing-fast.

Answer (score 2):

Use `time.strptime()`

```
>>> int(mktime(strptime('January 2, 2012', '%B %d, %Y')))
1325422800
>>> int(mktime(strptime('2012-01-05 13:01:51', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
1325728911
>>> int(mktime(strptime('2012-01-05', '%Y-%m-%d')))
1325682000
```

Comment: What has this do to with the question? The question is about parsing dates without knowledge of the date format

Comment: Everything - if you don't know the format, you have to guess multiple times. Try tonnes of different formats, catching the exceptions, or use a library like dateutil which should make it only partially easier. OP is trying to solve a problem which can't really be solved trivially, but is complaining about having to write a lot of cases.. don't allow users to manually enter dates. Ever.

Comment: No solution deals with ambigious date formats. And not guessing is better than *wild* guessing

Answer (score -1):

Check out this post :

[What is the formula for calculating a timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309012/what-is-the-formula-for-calculating-a-timestamp)

it's in PHP but does the job

Comment: PHP has a great function, strtotime(), but it doesn't seem like anything similar exists natively in Python without the use of 3rd party libraries.

Comment: I don't think this helps. The question is about how to figure out what date a string is referring to, not how to calculate a timestamp given a known date.